# How to queue functions within a JS class until an essential ajax request is done

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm building a javascript object which mainly should send an authentication ajax request before processing any other function on it.

Example:

```
hello={
say:function(txt){
alert(txt);
},
auth:function(){
... ajax ...
}
}

hello.say("hello world!");
```

The alert should not be triggered until the authentication ajax request is successfully fetched. It's like queuing any functions to the object until the initialization is done.

P.S. the auth should be automatically fired when the page is fully loaded.

- EDIT

Attempt to use SLaks method:

```
functionQueue = [];
function exec(func) {
    if (functionQueue){
        functionQueue.push(func);
    }else{ 
        func();
    }
}


hello={
say:function(txt){
alert(txt);
},
auth:function(){
ajax.post("http://www.hello.com",function(resp){
        var queue = functionQueue;
        functionQueue = false;    //Prevent re-entrancy
        for (var i = 0; i < queue.length; i++){
            queue[i]();
        }
});
}
}

function start(){
hello.auth();
}

window.addEventListener("load", start, false);
hello.say("hello world!");
```

Would absolutely appreciate your help.

Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you need to be using callbacks

Comment: You aren't actually calling `exec` anywhere.

Comment: [Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SLaks/CxvaQ/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make an array of functions to execute, push each function to the array if the request isn't finished yet, then loop through the array executing functions when the AJAX request finishes.

For example:

```
var functionQueue = [];
function exec(func) {
    if (functionQueue)
        functionQueue.push(func);
    else    //AJAX request already finished
        func();
}
$.ajax({
    ...
    success: function(...) {
        ...
        var queue = functionQueue;
        functionQueue = false;    //Prevent re-entrancy
        for (var i = 0; i < queue.length; i++)
            queue[i]();
    }
});
```

**EDIT**: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SLaks/CxvaQ/)

**2<sup>nd</sup> EDIT**:  To use `exec` inside an object, it can be useful to preserve `this`:

```
var functionQueue = [];
function exec(func, context) {
    if (functionQueue){
        functionQueue.push(function() { func.call(context); });
    } else {
        func.call(context);
    }
}

var hello = {
    say: function(txt){
        exec(function() {
            alert(txt);   //this still works
        }, this);
    },
    auth: function(){
        $.get("/echo/json/", function(resp){

            var queue = functionQueue;
            functionQueue = false;    //Prevent re-entrancy
            for (var i = 0; i < queue.length; i++){
                queue[i]();
            }
        });
    }
};


hello.say("hello world!");
hello.auth();
```

You might want to put the queue inside your object:

```
var hello = {
    functionQueue: [],
    exec: function(func) {
        if (this.functionQueue){
            this.functionQueue.push(func);
        } else {
            func.call(this);
        }
    },
    say: function(txt){
        this.exec(function() {
            alert(txt);   //this still works
        });
    },
    auth: function(){
        var me = this;
        $.get("/echo/json/", function(resp){
            alert('AJAX finished!');

            var queue = me.functionQueue;
            functionQueue = false;    //Prevent re-entrancy
            for (var i = 0; i < queue.length; i++){
                queue[i].call(me);
            }
        });
    }
};


hello.say("hello world!");
hello.auth();
```

Comment: @SLaks thanks for the answer, however i can't figure out how to implement the exec() within the object, can you please give an example based on the one i've provided?

Comment: @David: `exec(someFunction)` or `exec(function() { ... })`.

Comment: it says that functionQueue is undefined, because this is an object and it kinda can't get the global vars, i've removed the "var" and still not working, i will appreciate if you please type in an example based on my object structure.

Comment: @David: I have no idea what you're saying.  If you don't understand my code, you should learn more Javascript; it's nothing special.

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/4693/why-are-so-many-programmers-arrogant

Comment: I'm sorry, but that's not arrogance.  My code is just an array and a function that uses it.  You may be having trouble with `this`; please show me your attempt.

Comment: I've added my attempt to the post, Thanks.

Comment: it appears that @Slaks is using jQuery while David isn't.... David, please go take a look at jQuery, specifically the $.ajax call... http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: @Father: That shouldn't be relevant.

Comment: Hi, the problem is that i don't want to call exec() in every call, so the exec() should be inside the hello object.

Comment: @David: Then you can wrap the contents of each method in an `exec` call.  Note that `this` will not be preserved.